# PHP Division function equivalent to array_product

Tags: php, arrays, division

I'm looking for an equivalent to the PHP function array_product http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-product.php in that sense, that I would like to have a division on two values in an array. How do I do this? (And why doesn't it exist yet?)

Comment: The division doesn't have the associative property, so it's harder to define a `array_divison`: in which order should the function do the division?

Comment: the values are integers and the former value should be divided through the following value (pairs of two values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean like this? It's quite strange.

```
function array_div(array $arr)
{
    $first = array_shift($arr);
    foreach($arr as $num)
    {
        $first /= $num;
    }
    return $first;
}

echo array_div([100, 25, 0.5]); //8
echo array_div([99, 3]); //33
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`array_reduce()`](http://php.net/array_reduce):

```
$arr = array(100, 25, 0.5);
$initial = array_shift($arr);
$res = array_reduce($arr, function($r, $v) { return $v == 0 ? $r : ($r / $v); } , $initial);
```

Of course add some checks to see if `$v` is zero.